# Phonegap not returning base64encoded data

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I am using Phonegap and the camera application. I want to obtain a base64 encoded string. but can't get it to work. I am always getting a system path of the image. I need to retrieve the string.

```
function clickPhoto() 
{
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, 
    { 
        quality: 25, 
        destinationType:  destinationType.FILE_URI 

    });
}
```

I need to know how to get the base64 encoded string. I read somewhere on stack that the default of phonegap now returns file path. I need a base64.

Please suggest.

Comment: see the solution posted. That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, It's working now. however i can't assign the string to an <input> tag. Any help on this. I am accepting your answer anyways.

Comment: @user1900588 `<input>` or `<img>` tag? are you going to set this base64 string to image.?

Comment: No need to bother. It's working on my device. Thanks a lot again. May be my avd's heap not big enough. but good on phone.